# JSON parsing for Expandable ListView in Android

Tags: android, json

I am new to Android and I want to make an Expandable *Listview* in Android, but I am having problem in parsing json. I want to parse the following json:

```
[
  {
    "ref": "000051",
    "name": "DURA GREEN",
    "desc": "DURA GREEN 30 TO 0",
    "price": "29.000",
    "skus": [
      {
        "barcode": "000051046008",
        "color": "KHAKI R",
        "size": "42",
        "price": "29.00"
      },
      {
        "barcode": "000051046009",
        "color": "KHAK",
        "size": "44",
        "price": "29.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ref": "000072",
    "name": "WHITE DURA",
    "desc": "WHITE DURABLE 30 - 54",
    "price": "29.000",
    "skus": [
      {
        "barcode": "000072043010",
        "color": "WHITE L",
        "size": "48",
        "price": "29.00"
      },
      {
        "barcode": "000072043011",
        "color": "WHITE L",
        "size": "50",
        "price": "29.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ref": "000078",
    "name": "EBAY KARLSON",
    "desc": "SMART WHITE TROUSERS WITH PRIE",
    "price": "34.000",
    "skus": [
      {
        "barcode": "000078042002",
        "color": "WHITE R",
        "size": "30",
        "price": "34.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ref": "000053",
    "name": "DURA BLACK",
    "desc": "DURA BLACK WAIST 30 TO 54",
    "price": "19.000",
    "skus": [
      {
        "barcode": "000053038004",
        "color": "BLACK S",
        "size": "36",
        "price": "19.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ref": "000080",
    "name": "DURA WHITE  EBY",
    "desc": "WHITE DURABLE 30 - 44",
    "price": "34.000",
    "skus": [
      {
        "barcode": "000080042007",
        "color": "WHITE R",
        "size": "51",
        "price": "37.00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ref": "000025",
    "name": "DURABLEPRESS",
    "desc": "DURABLEPRESS 30 TO 50 WAIST",
    "price": "19.000",
    "skus": [
      {
        "barcode": "000025022002",
        "color": "NAVY S",
        "size": "30",
        "price": "19.00"
      },
      {
        "barcode": "000025022003",
        "color": "NAVY S",
        "size": "30",
        "price": "19.00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

LogCat is showing error as:

> 08-03 23:38:34.664: W/System.err(23554): org.json.JSONException: Index
>   2 out of range [0..2) 08-03 23:38:34.674: W/System.err(23554):    at
>   org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:282) 08-03 23:38:34.674:
>   W/System.err(23554):  at
>   org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(JSONArray.java:510) 08-03
>   23:38:34.674: W/System.err(23554):    at
>   com.example.webservice.NetworkOperation.SearchList(NetworkOperation.java:654)
>   08-03 23:38:34.674: W/System.err(23554):  at
>   com.example.webservice.NetworkOperation.doInBackground(NetworkOperation.java:98)
>   08-03 23:38:34.674: W/System.err(23554):  at
>   com.example.webservice.NetworkOperation.doInBackground(NetworkOperation.java:1)
>   08-03 23:38:34.674: W/System.err(23554):  at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 08-03 23:38:34.674:
>   W/System.err(23554):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 08-03
>   23:38:34.674: W/System.err(23554):    at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 08-03
>   23:38:34.674: W/System.err(23554):    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   08-03 23:38:34.674: W/System.err(23554):  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   08-03 23:38:34.674: W/System.err(23554):  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Code used is:

```
try {
            group_list = new ArrayList<Model_Search_Group>();
            ArrayList<Model_Search_Child> child_list;
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            result = httpClient.execute(postRequest, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("---result" + result);
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                child_list = new ArrayList<Model_Search_Child>();
                JSONObject jsonObj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                System.out.println("---json" + jsonObj);
                Model_Search_Group data = new Model_Search_Group();
                data.setItemRef((jsonObj.getString("ref")));
                data.setName((jsonObj.getString("name")));
                data.setDesc((jsonObj.getString("desc")));
                data.setPrice((jsonObj.getString("price")));
                JSONArray obj2 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("skus");

                for (int j = 0; j < obj2.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject json = obj2.getJSONObject(i);
                    System.out.println("---json" + json);
                    Model_Search_Child data2 = new Model_Search_Child();
                    data2.setBarcode((json.getString("barcode")));
                    data2.setColor((json.getString("color")));
                    data2.setSize((json.getString("size")));
                    data2.setPrice(json.getString("price"));
                    child_list.add(data2);
                }

                data.setChildItems(child_list);
                group_list.add(data);
                System.out.println("groupsize" + group_list.size());
            }
```

Comment: Please post the parsing code

Comment: Try using by GSON ,have a look at following tutorial:- http://www.nkdroid.com/2014/11/json-object-parsing-using-url-in-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 2nd for loop, replace `JSONObject json = obj2.getJSONObject(i);` by `JSONObject json = obj2.getJSONObject(j);`

Comment: Ahhh!! I have made such a stupid mistake. Thanks Chung Pham for the answer, It saved my life :D